# Axios request returns 401 despite having an authorization header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to patch data to a django API using axios using this snippet:

```js
nextQuestion = () => {
  if (this.state.currentIndex === 0) return;

  const token = this.props.token;
  const configs = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
    },
    data: {
      quiztaker: this.state.data[0].quiz.quiztakers_set.id,
      question: this.state.data[0].quiz.question_set[this.state.currentIndex]
        .id,
      answer: Number(this.state.answer),
    },
  };
  console.log(configs);
  axios
    .patch("/api/save-answer/", configs)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });

  this.setState({
    currentIndex: this.state.currentIndex - 1
  });
};
```

I have confirmed that the token does indeed exist and that it is authorised to access and make changes to that endpoint through insomnia. Did i do anything wrong with how i set up axios? or is there something else i'm not getting? Apologies if it's an obvious mistake, still quite new to react.

Comment: What content-type is the endpoint expecting?

Comment: @Anuga application/json

Comment: tried `axis.patch(url, data, config)...`?

Comment: @Anuga thank you! separating the body and headers worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `axios.patch()` it should be executed `axios.patch(url, data, config)...`.

```
const data = {
  "quiztaker": this.state.data[0].quiz.quiztakers_set.id,
  "question": this.state.data[0].quiz.question_set[this.state.currentIndex].id,
  "answer": Number(this.state.answer),
};
const token = this.props.token;
const configs = {
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": `Token ${token}`,
  },
};

axios
  .patch("/api/save-answer/", data, configs)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```